# Как правильно организовать работу с ролями в react/redux приложении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

В приложении есть роли(admin, manager, user и т.д.) у всех разный набор разрешений. На бэке все замечательно разрулил. Не могу понять как в redux приложении организовать всё.
Как должен быть реализован роутинг?

Подскажите что почитать на эту тему или поделитесь опытом кто имел дело c чем-то подобным. С реактом совсем недавно работаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно для разных ролей использовать разные роуты-врапперы с компонентами или функциями, в которых будет проверка роли пользователя.

Пример таких роутов:

```
<Route path='/admin' component={AdminWrapper} >
    <Route path='/path1' component={AdminComponent1} >
    <Route path='/path2' component={AdminComponent2} >
</Route>
<Route path='/user' component={UserWrapper} >
    <Route path='/path3' component={UserComponent1} >
    <Route path='/path4' component={UserComponent2} >
</Route>
```

В компоненте AdminWrapper в componentWillMount надо проверять роль пользователя (которая хранится в редаксе после логина) и сверить с правами этого компонента и его дочерних. Если проверка провалена, то выполнять редирект на 401-страницу или другой роут, подготовленный Вами для таких случаев.

Как пример:

```
class AdminWrapper extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.check_role()
    }
    check_role() {
        if(this.props.user.role !== 'admin')
            this.props.router.replace('/unauthorized')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AdminWrapper)
```